# Azure Build Pipeline with There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am doing DevOps on my react-native projects. I want to build the project and want automation on iOS app deployment. But when I try to build it gives following error:

> Check dependencies Code Signing Error: There are no accounts
>   registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode Code
>   Signing Error: No profiles for 'ios.kapiling' were found:  Xcode
>   couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
>   'ios.kapiling'. Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for
>   product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'

Here is my YAML script:

```
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: Xcode
  inputs:
    actions: '-allowProvisioningUpdates archive '
    configuration: Release
    sdk: iphoneos11.4
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/community_app.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'community_app'
    xcodeVersion: 10
    signingOption: auto
    teamId: XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I have uploaded the cert and profile to secure files but still I'm not able to build.

Comment: I have successfully build the app. Please share you error here

Comment: I resolved my error too. Thanks. The problem was the mismatch in profile in Xcode and pipeline.

Comment: @Ishmeet I have same problem, How we can find this mismatch. Do we want to resolve it in XCode or Need to edit any project file?

Answer (score 1):

From the error you can understand that an Xcode app must be signed and provisioned to run on a device or be published to the App Store.

he signing and provisioning process needs access to your P12 signing certificate and one or more provisioning profiles. The [Install Apple Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops) and [Install Apple Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops) tasks make these available to Xcode during a build.

The following snippet installs an Apple P12 certificate and provisioning profile in the build agent's Keychain. Then, it builds, signs, and provisions the app with Xcode. Finally, the certificate and provisioning profile are automatically removed from the Keychain at the end of the build, regardless of whether the build succeeded or failed. For more details, see [Sign your mobile app during CI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=azure-devops).

```
# The `certSecureFile` and `provProfileSecureFile` files are uploaded to the Azure Pipelines secure files library where they are encrypted.
# The `P12Password` variable is set in the Azure Pipelines pipeline editor and marked 'secret' to be encrypted.
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'chrisid_iOSDev_Nov2018.p12'
    certPwd: $(P12Password)

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: '6ffac825-ed27-47d0-8134-95fcf37a666c.mobileprovision'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: ''
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'default' # Options: nosign, default, manual, auto
    useXcpretty: 'false' # Makes it easier to diagnose build failures
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, after installing the certificate and profile. My profile doesn't have an UUID in its name. Is it mandatory or is it just a string? I downloaded it from Apple's Developer website.

Comment: I have this issue too. @Ipacheco

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://damienaicheh.github.io/ios/azure/devops/2019/12/05/build-sign-your-ios-application-using-azure-devops-en) helped me to solve the error. If you use Cocoapods and have next error: **Xcode builds suddenly failing with message 'error:  does not support provisioning profiles**<, then try to add this snippet to **.pod** file. Here is an original [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9984#issuecomment-483968562)

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```